# Creating Android LIbrary Project Jar Using gradle with dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

I'm trying to build .Jar file out of Android Library Project (Non-executable) using gradle with dependencies, but I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError because it is  accessing one of the files from the dependency modules.

So far i've tried FatJar method but it includes everything in the Jar file except the Dependant libraries.

What should i do?

**UPDATE**

My Gradle.build file

```
apply plugin: 'android'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        sourceSets {
            main {
                java {
                    srcDir 'src/main/java'
                }
                resources {
                    srcDir 'src/../lib'
                }

            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    }

    task deleteOldJar(type: Delete) {
        delete 'build/libs/AndroidPlugin.jar'
    }
    task exportJar(type: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar) {
        //from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
        //from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
       // archiveName = "yourjar.jar"

        from {

            configurations.runtime.collect {
                it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
            }

            configurations.compile.collect {
                it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
            }
        }
        into('release/')
        include('classes.jar')
        ///Give whatever name you want to give
        rename('classes.jar', 'AndroidPlugin.jar')
    }

    exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)
```

Comment: DId you got any solution? I am also building a jar library file. Please check my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373117/error-while-creating-own-jar-library-for-android-project)

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice plugin which can produce Fat Jars easy: https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin . But it works with `java` plugin which conflicts with `com.android.library` btw.

So, I have found a little workaround. Every Jar file is a Zip archive actually.
It means that we can unzip it and add its content to a new archive.

There is a snippet of code which produces Fat Jar and pushes it to the defined
local/remote Maven repository:

```
...

apply plugin: 'maven-publisher'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bundleRelease
        }

        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact fatJar
        }
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    from (zipTree('libs/library-one.jar'))
    from (zipTree('libs/library-two.jar'))
    from (zipTree('libs/library-three.jar'))
    from ('build/intermediates/classes/release/') {
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.class'
        exclude '**/R$*.class'
        exclude '**/R.class'
    }
}

...
```

Than you need just run:

```
$ ./gradlew clean build publishToMavenLocal
```

P.S. Also you can iterate through your `libs` (including `*.jar`) folder if you do not want to write every lib separately.

Answer (score 1):

In your Project , creates folder inside APP named 'libs' , and copy the jar of playservices. This is for Android Studio.

```
APP
 -libs
 -src
 -build
```

In your build gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.so'])


    compile files('libs/NameOfJar.jar')



}
```

Comment: I don't know  if you understood the question correctly.
I want to :
Export a jar of my Android Library Project, with maven dependancies packeged inside because i'm trying to use this Jar in another project, but i'm getting NoClassDefFoundError.

I'm pasting my current gradle file above please check.